# How to pass a custom variable from CLI to webpack.config.js

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-5

I'm looking to be able to do something along the lines of `npm run watch -- http://site.local` and then be able to access that url inside my webpack config file.

I've been looking into webpack custom args and the like but they all seem to only cover hard coding a single value into my npm script and don't allow for passing the variables from the cli. I also tried to get this working with cross-env but I was not able to get that tow work either. When ever I try to do either webpack complains that it has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `--env` flag along with the `webpack` command

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).